# List id not found: android:list

Tags: android, listview

Iam trying to find the id for the listview, but it dosen't work just typing like this:
this.view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
R.id.list -> dosen't work, cause it can't find the id
Iam using my own custom made list.

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: if you are using a ListActivity you can call getListView()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
</ListView>
```

To obtain it:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```